# Creating 0..1 to 0..1 relationships with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'd like to create 0..1 to 0..1 relationship, however, for some reason when trying to insert to the database, Entity Framework keeps telling me:

"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."

Part of my code:

```
public class Usable {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("ObjectOfInterest")] -> uncommenting this causes:
      //The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'MentionID' on type
      //'MetaDataModeller.Models.Core.Category' is not valid. The navigation property
      //'ObjectOfInterest' was not found on the dependent type 
      //'MetaDataModeller.Models.Core.Category'. The Name value should be a valid 
      //navigation property name.
    //[ForeignKey("Mention")] -> uncommenting this makes no difference
    public int? MentionID { get; set; }
    public virtual ObjectOfInterest Mention { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectOfInterest {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Usable Use { get; set; }
}
```

My ancestor of DbContext has this code in overriden OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Usable>()
    .HasOptional(usable => usable.Mention)
    .WithOptionalDependent(obj => obj.Use);
```

So - is it possible to create 0..1 to 0..1 relationship? How? / Why not? / Is there a way to get around it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Strangely enough, I managed to solve the problem by adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] to the ID property in Usable. No idea, why things work like this, though.